# How many times is the digit $3$ repeated in $9^{666}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How many times is the digit $3$ repeated in the number $9^{666}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't even know how to start this problem.

Comment: The answer seems to be 60. (done with pari-gp)

Comment: Once again an elementary number theory question with no contexts or visible attempts get a lot of votes...

Comment: Might be useful what you know and where the problem comes from...

Comment: I tried to do: 9^(666)=a3+b3+c3...+n3 and solve for all the variables but that's not possible!

Comment: I can confirm 60, with mathematica 'Count[IntegerDigits[9^666], 3]'

Comment: You can find the number of digits $D$ in $a^b$ with
$$D=\lfloor 1+b\cdot \log_{10} a \rfloor$$

So $9^{666}$ has $D=\lfloor 1 + 666 \cdot \log_{10} 9 \rfloor=636$ digits.

Assumung every digit 0-9 has the same chance to appear, you'll get $D_3 \approx 63.6$ times digit 3.

Any suggestions how to improve?

Comment: As the tags suggest, it might be an olympiad problem, and I surely would like to see a solution which does not include computer programs. I don't think this question needs more context than the famous batman question...

Comment: Unlikely to be an olympiad problem, because with a computer it is trivial, and without a computer it is also trivial, just very very very tedious. No brain power required.